# How I can create multi ouput folders into the "/dist/" folder - Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, output

In the  destination directory (/dist/) I would like to create three directories  with IMAGES  folder, CSS folder, JS folder, multi output directories similar to the following screenshoot:

[image: captura]

My current  entry looks something like this:

[image]

My `webpack.config.js`  looks something like this (this code works but it doesn't create the structure that I want ):

```
                var path = require("path");
            const webpack = require('webpack');
            const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
            const FileManagerPlugin = require('filemanager-webpack-plugin');
            const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin("css/[name]-1.0.0.css");
            const extractSASS = new ExtractTextPlugin("es/[name].css");
            module.exports = function(env) {
            var isProd = false;
            if (env != null && env.production) {
                isProd = true;
            }
            var jsDev = "./js/[name]-bundle.js";
            var jsProd = "./js/[name]-" + date_string() + ".js";
            var configJs = isProd ? jsProd : jsDev;
            return {
                context: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
                entry: {
                    specials: './js/specials.js',
                    checkout: './js/checkout.js',
                    mobile: './js/mobile.js',
                    screen: './js/screen.js',
                    custom: './js/app.js'
                },
                output: {
                    path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
                    filename: configJs
                },
                module: {
                    rules: [{
                        test: /\.css$/,
                        use: extractCSS.extract({
                            fallback: "style-loader",
                            use: "css-loader"
                        })
                    }, {
                        test: /\.scss$/,
                        use: extractSASS.extract({
                            fallback: "style-loader",
                            use: ["css-loader", "sass-loader"]
                        })
                    }, {
                        test: /\.(jpg|svg|png|gif)$/,
                        exclude: /fonts/,
                        loaders: [{
                            loader: 'file-loader',
                            options: {
                                name: '[name].[ext]',
                                outputPath: './images/',
                                publicPath: ''
                            }
                        }]
                    }, {
                        test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                        exclude: /images/,
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: 'fonts/[name].[ext]',
                            publicPath: ''
                        }
                    }]
                },
                plugins: [
                    extractSASS
                ]
            };
```

Any help will be appreciated,

Thank you,

Comment: What's the structure of the source directory? Do you just need the same input files duplicated into each of the three destination directories?

Comment: The entry will be

    entry: {
      specials: './js/specials.js',
      checkout: './js/checkout.js',
      mobile: './js/mobile.js',
      screen: './js/screen.js',
      custom: './js/app.js'
    }

Comment: You have that in your code already. Please answer my two questions so we can help you easier.

Comment: I add new screenshot with the entry "SRC"  that should be create the output "dist" with three destination directories.
Thank you for your help ;)

Comment: What source files do you need in each dist location? I'm not understanding your intended process.

Comment: From my src directories:

| checkout --> /dist/checkout/ 
| specials --> /dist/specials/
| mob --> /dist/mobile/
....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Focus on this part of configuration:

```
var jsDev = "./js/[name]-bundle.js";
var jsProd = "./js/[name]-" + date_string() + ".js";

var configJs = isProd ? jsProd : jsDev;

output: {
  path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
  filename: configJs
},
```

If you change jsDev and jsProd to this:

```
var jsDev = "./[name]/[name]-bundle.js";
var jsProd = "./[name]/[name]-" + date_string() + ".js";
```

webpack will create folders with your entries names (specials, checkout etc.).

If you wish more advanced approach you may check this part of webpack documentation: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-filename ,

especially the part:

**Using function to return the filename:**

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  output: {
    filename: (chunkData) => {
      return chunkData.chunk.name === 'main' ? '[name].js': '[name]/[name].js';
    },
  }
};
```

There are some resources you might want to also check:

https://hackernoon.com/webpack-creating-dynamically-named-outputs-for-wildcarded-entry-files-9241f596b065

https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-entry-plus

https://www.npmjs.com/package/multiple-bundles-webpack-plugin